# How to get all the users corresponding to the acl role?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, parsing, parse-platform

I need to get all the users from that role. I already know the code for this, but I don't know how to get a user from the role.

I only know that I need to use the `getUsers()` function on the role but there is where I get stuck.

My code:

```
self.getCompanyUsers = function getCompanyUsers() {
    $rootScope.displayLoading = true;
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
    userQuery.contains('name', $state.params.id);

    userQuery.find().then(function(roles) {
        $scope.users = roles;
        $rootScope.displayLoading = false;      
    }).then(function() { 
        console.log(roles.getUsers());

    })
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are a few issues with the code you've provided, which will need to be fixed before.

First; your promise flow seems a bit off. You are trying to continue it without returning anything. I'm not sure why you would need to do this inside a promise chain, as you don't have to wait for anything to complete. So you should remove the second `then`, unless you have omitted something from the code you posted.

Secondly; you are trying to call `getUsers()` on an array of Parse.Role's. There are a few ways round this, depending on the end use of this function:

- You can change the `userQuery.find()` to `userQuery.first()`, this will only return a single object and `roles.getUsers()` will be valid.
- Or you can loop through the results you get from the existing query and call `getUsers()` on each one. I would suggest this isn't what you want to do, as it could result in a lot of queries on the User object and there is likely a better alternative if this is what you want.

Thirdly; the `getUsers()` will simply return the Parse.Relation and not the users in the role. To get the users, you have to get the query object first. As so: `role.getUsers().query();`

This is a normal Parse.Query and you can use it as such. For example, `role.getUsers().query().find()`

If I am right in thinking, you will be wanting something similar to this:

```
    self.getCompanyUsers = function getCompanyUsers() {
        $rootScope.displayLoading = true;
        var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        userQuery.contains('name', $state.params.id);
        userQuery.first().then(function(role) {
            $scope.users = role;


            if(!role)
            {
                //check a role has been found
                return Parse.Promise.error("No role found")
            }

            //role.getUsers() will be the Parse.Relation
            //role.getUsers().query() will be a normal Parse.Query
            return role.getUsers().query().find();

        }).then(function(users)
            {
                //users will be an array of the users in the role, depending on ACL/CLP.
                console.log(users);
                $rootScope.displayLoading = false;
            }
        )
    };
```