# How can I access & sterilize my Javascript user object from Parse server before sending to client?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I do not have a clue why I cannot sterilize my user object array server side. I am having issues accessing any properties at all server side no matter what I've tried I get either errors or empty results. In my Flutter/Dart code I can access any properties as normal but of course I do not want users to be able to get all such data.

So the question is, why can't I access properties server side and how can I do this?

EDIT: On some help in comments it has been discovered that this "object" is not in fact an array, this makes things more difficult. Also does not make sense that I can access the "not array" normally in my flutter dart code... any ideas whats wrong?

[For below I am following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965279/13945484)
My code that works, returning a list of Parse User objects:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("ccRoleUsersQuery", async function(request) {
    const query = await new Parse.Query(Parse.Role).equalTo('users', request.user).find({ useMasterKey: true })
    let users = query[0].getUsers().query().find({ useMasterKey: true });
    let steralizedResults = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        let name = users[i].get("name");         // Does not access object
      let publicKey = users[i]["publicKey"];     // Does not access object
      steralizedResults.push(name);          
      steralizedResults.push(publicKey);    
    }
    return users;            // steralizedResults if used returns empty array
  });
```

Users array returned as above:

```
[{username: user003, email: user003@parse.com, createdAt: 2021-09-26T23:37:37.594Z,
updatedAt: 2021-10-05T01:25:43.989Z, publicKey: 445trTREttY654FFFGgt5ydfsg, name: 003, ACL: {6m9LPbxD8V: {read: true, write: true}}, objectId: 6m9LPbxD8V, __type: Object, className: _User}, 
{username: user004, createdAt: 2021-10-03T22:19:27.754Z, updatedAt: 2021-10-06T23:24:07.576Z, email: user004@parse.com, publicKey: GTRg554gtr8yvfdsv43fdsv334, name:
004, ACL: {t9joISsGwO: {read: true, write: true}}, objectId: t9joISsGwO, __type: Object, className: _User}]
```

Comment: You are just returning the `users`. That being said I have no idea how that `.find` method works. It's not the same as `Array.prototype.find`, anyways.

Comment: Yes, just returning the users. It is very incomprehensible & mysterious as to why I can't access the objects server side...

Comment: `console.log(typeof users)`. What do you get?

Comment: 2021-10-07T00:29:54.074Z - 
object

Comment: `console.log(typeof users[0]);`. What do you see?

Comment: i get: undefined

Comment: `console.log(users instanceof Array)`. If you are not getting `true` then that's not an Array to begin with. Arrays are Objects that  are instanceof Array, in JavaScript. Note that `typeof null` is `'object'` in JavaScript, as well.

Comment: I get false! What does that mean, other than it's not an array? Do I need to go back to the drawing board getting my Users of role? Or is there a way to access this... whatever it is?

Comment: `Object.keys(users[i])`? e.g. maybe `users[i].toJSON()` is a thing?

Comment: Or `Object.keys(users)`, see if there's a `users.each` or something!

Comment: `Object.keys(users[i])` gives me `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` I tried `JSON.stringify(users[0])` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users[0]))` and neither work. This does make sense since discovering that the "array" looking thing is not actually an array. And finally `Object.keys(users)` returns empty array

Comment: Bahh, I suppose `Object.keys` was silly since `Object.keys([])` also returns empty array. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(users)` may be more useful? Or: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(users))`

Comment: Also, is this not async? Should there not be an `await` or, as these docs propose, `.find({ ..., success: list =>`? (https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/)

Comment: Thats it! Thats the problem! WOW, such a simple issue! Thank you very much for pointing that out. I thought I was going nuts over this haha. If your interested, post answer and I'll happily mark as answer as it deserves. Hopefully if anyone else makes such a silly mistake this can help them in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Tis the season to be async:

```
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    // results is an array of Parse.Object.
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
  }
});
```

Also special functions you can use on the `Parse.Query` object: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/parse/index.d.ts (search for `class Query`)